# How to set React.useState based on URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to set the following to different numbers based on the page the user is on using window.location.path

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);
```

I have tried if statement and I seem to get errors so my thinking was to set a params to

`<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

however while I understand I could do something like

```
<Route exact path="/:id" component={Home} />
```

the issue is the following as you can see below I have a number of set paths, the tabs in the nav bar are linked to the main path (/, /about, /news, /programs etc)

```
<Switch>
           <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
           <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
           <Route path="/news/:id" component={News} />
           <Route path="/programs/:id" component={Programs} />
           <Route path="/podcast/:id" component={Podcast} />


</Switch>
```

I want to be able to send a number with each Route so that way I can just set the following with something like

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState({pageID});
```

I was thinking something like

```
<Route path="/podcast/:id" pageID="4" component={Podcast} />
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

let say that you are using this in component `News`

The first step to be able to extract the param out of the link is using `withRouter`

1. Import it in your component `News` file: `import { withRouter } from "react-router";`
2. We need to wrap the component inside the `withRouter` HOC as follows:

```
//instead of exporting it as export default News.
export default withRouter(News) //this will make the API we need available at the component's props
```

3. supposing you want to do that:

`const [value, setValue] = React.useState({pageID});`

at the component mount, inside `componentDidMount` we can extract the param as follows:

`const { id } = this.props.match.params //the id the user navigated to: /news/:id`

and then you can use the id to update your state.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass parameters to component with render method.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Home pageId=1 {...props} />} />
  <Route path="/about/" render={(props) => <About pageId=2 {...props} />}  />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple params to the path as -

```
path="/podcast/:id/:pageId"
```

And to retrieve -

```
this.props.match.params.pageId
```